# Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebService2.CustomServiceProxy.MemoryStream' to 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Tags: c#, web-services

I created on server 1 the following method :

```
public System.IO.MemoryStream ms(string sessionID, int customerID)
```

On server 2 i'm sending parameters to this method with :

```
CustomService customService = new WebService2.CustomServiceProxy.CustomService();
System.IO.MemoryStream MS = customService.ms(s.SessionID, Cust.Id);
```

CustomServiceProxy being the name of the web reference that points to server 1.

So when doing this, I'm receing the message :

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebService2.CustomServiceProxy.MemoryStream' to 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't return a memory stream, return a byte array.

Comment: Your web-proxy creation will have had some option like "use existing types" which will *not* have been checked. The proxy creation process has recreated a `MemoryStream` class. You can avoid this by changing the options for proxy generation. **But** as Lasse suggests, from such a service you should be returning a byte array, not a `MemoryStream`. You can get a byte array from a `MemoryStream` using the `GetBuffer` method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My First thought is a cast. Something like this:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream MS = (System.IO.MemoryStream)customService.ms(s.SessionID, Cust.ID);
```

Not sure if that'll work, but there it is. Good luck

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is right you should convert the memory stream to a byte array and return that.